# Retrieving Data of a combobox item -Telerik MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, telerik-mvc

my application is asp.net MVC, I am using Telerik MVC Combobox, using ViewData, I send items as:

```
 people.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John", viewed = true });

<% Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
       .Name("ComboBox")
       .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable<Person>)ViewData["people"], "Id", "Name"))
       .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("ComboBox_onChange")
       .OnLoad("ComboBox_onLoad")
       .OnOpen("ComboBox_OnOpen"))
       .Render();
%>
```

I can get the text of a specific item using:

```
 var item = combobox.dropDown.$items.eq(0);
 alert(item.text());
```

Any idea how I can get the data of this item to check if the value of viewed if it is true of false.
I tried:

```
   alert(item.Value.split('|'));
```

but got this error:  Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean "get the data of this item to check if the value of viewed if it is true of false." ? Elaborate this more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Client API documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html#ClientMethods)

Basically you need to get a reference to the combobox plugin first:

```
var combo = $('#ComboBox').data('tComboBox');
```

Then you can call whatever method you need:

```
alert( combo.value() );
```

EDIT:

Your combobox is currently bound to a `SelectList` where the `Value` is Person.Id and `Text` is Person.Name. The "viewed" property is not stored anywhere. You could include it as part of the `Value`, retrieve the value as I described above, and then `split()` to get the "viewed" part:

```
Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
    .Items(items =>
    {
        // pseudo-code
        foreach (person)
            items.Add().Text(person.Name).Value(person.Id + "_" + person.Viewed)
    })
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this will give me the index value, however I am looking for if the viewed is true or false.